# Image as a post variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am working on a site where there is a feature for users to be able to sign directly on the webpage using a canvas free form pen tool. When users click the 'apply signature' button the signature that the user drew is converted into an image and saved on the page as an `<img src="">` (as you can see  in the code below). Up until this point everything works great.

The problem is, When the user submits the form, I am trying to get the newly created canvas image to submit with it as a post variable and render on the `process.php` page as the signature that was signed. It appears that image (toDataURL()) gets passed as a post variable, but for some reason it does not render on the process.php page. It appears like the image source is not found.

I am new to javascript and I have been trying to fix this problem for days now, I would appreciate any help with fixing this. Many thanks in advance!

Markup

```
<div class="signature-field">
    Sign:
    <span class="sketch-container">
       <canvas id="simple_sketch" width="350" height="100"></canvas>
    </span> 
    Date: <input name="signature-date" type="text"><br/>
    <div class="signature-buttons">
        <span class="save-signature">Apply Signature | </span> 
        <span class="reset-canvas">| Reset Signature</span><br/>
    </div>
</div>


<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input id="signature" name="signature" type="hidden">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    var sktch = $('#simple_sketch').sketch();
    var cleanCanvas = $('#simple_sketch')[0];

    $('.save-signature').click(function () {
        /* replace canvas with image */
        var canvas = document.getElementById("simple_sketch");
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $('#simple_sketch').replaceWith('<img src="' + img + '"/>');
        $('.signature-buttons').replaceWith('');
        document.getElementById("signature").value = $('.sketch-container').html();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're doing here, but if you want to post the image data through the hidden `signature` field, simply do this:

```
document.getElementById("signature").value = document.getElementById("simple_sketch").toDataURL("image/png");
```

As right now, it looks like you're posting the image data including `<img>` tags (`"<img src="<DataUrl>"/>"`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The data is getting passed the same way even after this modification, and the image source is still not found, thanks anyways.

Comment: Then the problem is probably in your server-side data (And I at least saved you a few lines of code). Can you sho us how you're trying to read the data, server-side?
Also, are you aware the `toDataURL` doesn't save the image anywhere? It sends the raw image data to the server, base64 encoded. You'll have to decode the image there.

Comment: I am reading the img signature data as a I would any other $_POST variable... `$_POST['signature']`...

Comment: Okay, but what's actually in it? (tip: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) it if it's huge)

Comment: That's without my modification. it still has the `<img>` in there.
Without that, it's a valid image.

Comment: Just replace your click handler assignment with [this code](http://pastebin.com/qJrAYnqX), then you should just get the image data in your php.

Answer (score 0):

How about your server-side code, is the img param output empty? Are you sure the img data is being sent through the request? Try some packet sniffing tool like Fiddler or Wireshark and analyze the contents of the request (You can also take a quick look with Firebug).

Perhaps you could try some other approach to convert the img data:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the image data is getting passed through the request, but when trying to render it after it gets passed as a $_POST var, the source is not found...

Comment: Just double-checking:are you testing this locally? Can you rule out any corrupt data/network issues?

Comment: Yes I can. I am testing it locally and non-locally and getting the same results.